# HP 8620 printer always shows as “Offline” in Windows 11 Settings > Printers area

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, windows-11, network-printer, hp

HP 8620 printer always shows as “Offline” in Windows 11 Settings > Printers area.

It has perfect Wi-Fi connection, with a Wi-Fi Extender right next to it. Our home only has one Wi-Fi network, the same name for 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz, the printer shows it is on the only Wi-Fi, and my PC shows it is on our only Wi-Fi.

I have tried many things:

- In Windows 11 Settings, remove printer, restart PC, reinstall printer.
- Remove printer, install printer from HP Smart.
- Power cycle  printer, restart PC.
- Changed printer sleep mode from 5 mins to 15 mins.
- Remove printer, reinstall with manual driver from HP Website.

When I am in Windows 11, the printer will work fine if it is awake, and I am able to print from any application, however, if I have not printed in a while, this printer will show as “Offline,” and the print jobs will pile up.

What can I do to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: If you print the WiFI settings for the printer, there should be a way to do this on the printer itself. Does it show you are connected to the same network as the computer in question?

Comment: Printer and PC are using our one and only WiFi. I notice you said "print the wifi settings for the printer". Have you not used HP Smart yet? You can view and change about 100 printer settings in there.

Comment: **I have an HP printer** My HP printer is able to print WiFi information about the network it’s connected to, I am trying to determine, if the printer is actually connected to the wireless network. So I have absolutely used HP Smart before, if you are going to be difficult, I can just forget about this question and delete my comments. Windows 11 22H2 has a compatibility blocker dealing with the type of printer drivers that HP Smart would use, can you confirm, the type of printer driver your printer is attempting to use. My printer connected through HP Smart, currently blocks Windows 11

Comment: This [advice](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Errors-or-Lights-Stuck-Print-Jobs/8620-all-in-one-printer-going-offline/td-p/4916985) keeps repeating in the HP forums. Please check if it relates to your printer.

Comment: I have an HP 8610 (essentially same printer).  Set up with the HP Driver on Windows 11 22H2  and it will always wake up. Try uninstalling the driver, restarting and installing it again. I can use HP Smart and it works but I choose to the use the HP desktop driver and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your printer is not in Use Printer Offline mode. Select Start > Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Printers & scanners. Then select your printer > Open print queue. Under Printer, make sure Use Printer Offline is not selected.

Now that you've accessed your printer settings, check to see if your printer is set to be offline:
Right-click on your printer and select “See what's printing.”
Click on “Printer” at the top left in the menu bar.
If "Use Printer Offline" is checked, please uncheck it.
Try printing your document.